# View array with over 1000 items in VSCode debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am working on a dotnet core project using VSCode and the C# Omnisharp extension.

My debug view looks like this:

[image: Debug View]
...
[image: Debug View End]

Is is possible to expand the full array? I want to view some lines around location 2163 but cannot view past 999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation of Omnisharp, and I see you opened [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1859) to track this already.

As [suggested](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1859#issuecomment-344070785), try using a linq query to filter down the data before inspecting it: `cFile.Skip(1000)`